# Jquery mobile let users find other users nearby

Tags: jquery-mobile, geolocation, gps

I'am building my first app using JQuery mobile.

I want to build a radar function. When the user opens the app it searches for users nearby en display's the distance.

How can i do this?

Comment: That a very big question and would require a fair amount of time to answer it or design it for you. You may have better luck building a simple app first and getting some experience with jQuery Mobile first.  You may find its not the best solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting tutorial that may provide some insight:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/html5-geolocation/